# ValueError when Assigning Values to 3D Numpy Array: 'operands could not be broadcast together with shapes' in LBM CFD Solver

Tags: python

I'm working on coding a CFD solver based on the Lattice Boltzmann Method (LBM) to analyze the flow around a square cylinder. However, when I try to compile, I encounter the following error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/sayad/Desktop/sanstitre0.py', wdir='C:/Users/sayad/Desktop')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File D:\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\sayad\desktop\sanstitre0.py:106
    geq,rho,ux,uy=init(M0=0.3)

  File c:\users\sayad\desktop\sanstitre0.py:41 in init
    eq(geq,rho,ux,uy)

  File c:\users\sayad\desktop\sanstitre0.py:72 in eq
    geq[:, :, 1:9] = w[1:] * rho * (1 + (c0**(-2)) * (ca[1:9, 0]*ux + ca[1:9, 1]*uy) + 0.5* (c0**-4) * (ca[1:9, 0]*ux + ca[1:9, 1]*uy)**2 - 0.5 * (c0**(-2)) * (ux**2 + uy**2))

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (8,) (80,40)
```

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

# Parametres du modele D2Q9
Re= 20 # Nombre de Reynolds (à faire varier)
ca= np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [-1, 0], [0, -1], [1, 1], [-1, 1], [-1, -1], [1, -1]]) # vitesses discrètes
op= -ca # symetrique de chaque vitesse discrète
w= np.array([4/9, 1/9, 1/36, 1/9, 1/36, 1/9, 1/36, 1/9, 1/36]) # coefficients omega_alpha
c0= 1/np.sqrt(3) # coefficient de vitesse du son

D= 4 # Resolution du cylindre (nombre de point dans le diamètre)

nx,ny= 20*D, 10*D
M0= 0.3

taug= (M0*D)/(c0*Re) + 1  # Temps de relaxation du modèle (défini en fonction du Reynolds)
nt= int((150*D)/(M0*c0))    # Nombre d'itération a définir

mask=np.zeros((nx,ny));
# Definition du cylindre => Choisir les bons indices pour placer
# le cylindre au centre du domaine en y et dans le premier tiers en x
cx1,cx2= int(8*D - 0.5*D), int(8*D + 0.5*D)
cy1,cy2= int(5*D - 0.5*D), int(5*D + 0.5*D)
mask[cx1:cx2,cy1:cy2]=1

def init(M0):
    # fonction d'initialisation des variables macroscopiques 
    # et de la fonction d'équilibre
    rho= np.ones((nx, ny)) * c0**2
    ux= np.full((nx, ny), M0 * c0)
    uy= np.zeros((nx, ny))
    geq=np.zeros((nx,ny,9))
    eq(geq,rho,ux,uy)
    return geq,rho,ux,uy 


def collide(gcoll,g,geq,taug):
    # Etape de collision
    gcoll[:,:,:]= g[:,:,:] - (1/taug)*(g[:,:,:] - geq[:,:,:])


def propagate(g,gcoll):
    # Etape de propagation
    g[:, :, 0] = gcoll[:, :, 0]
    g[:, :, 1] = gcoll[:, :, 1]
    g[:, :, 2] = gcoll[:, :, 2]
    g[:, :, 3] = gcoll[:, :, 3]
    g[:, :, 4] = gcoll[:, :, 4]
    g[:, :, 5] = gcoll[:, :, 5]
    g[:, :, 6] = gcoll[:, :, 6]
    g[:, :, 7] = gcoll[:, :, 7]
    g[:, :, 8] = gcoll[:, :, 8]

def macro(g,rho,ux,uy):
    # calcul des variables macro
    rho[:, :] = np.sum(g, axis=2)
    ux[:, :] = (g[:, :, 1] - g[:, :, 3] + g[:, :, 5] - g[:, :, 6] - g[:, :, 7] + g[:, :, 8]) / rho[:, :]
    uy[:, :] = (g[:, :, 2] - g[:, :, 4] + g[:, :, 5] + g[:, :, 6] - g[:, :, 7] - g[:, :, 8]) / rho[:, :]


def eq(geq,rho,ux,uy):
    # Calcul de la fonction d'équilibre
    geq[:, :, 0] = w[0] * rho * (1 - 0.5 * (c0**(-2)) * (ux**2 + uy**2))
    geq[:, :, 1:9] = w[1:] * rho * (1 + (c0**(-2)) * (ca[1:9, 0]*ux + ca[1:9, 1]*uy) + 0.5* (c0**-4) * (ca[1:9, 0]*ux + ca[1:9, 1]*uy)**2 - 0.5 * (c0**(-2)) * (ux**2 + uy**2))
    
def boundary(g,gcoll):
    # Conditions aux limites periodiques
    # Entree => quelles sont les g inconnues en entree
    g[0, :, 0] = gcoll[0, :, 0]
    g[0, :, 1:8] = gcoll[0, :, 1:8]
    g[0, :, 8] = gcoll[0, :, 8]
    # Sortie => quelles sont les g inconnues en sortie
    g[-1, :, 0] = gcoll[-1, :, 0]
    g[-1, :, 1:8] = gcoll[-1, :, 1:8]
    g[-1, :, 8] = gcoll[-1, :, 8]
    # Bas => quelles sont les g inconnues en bas
    g[:, 0, 0] = gcoll[:, 0, 0]
    g[:, 0, 1:8] = gcoll[:, 0, 1:8]
    g[:, 0, 8] = gcoll[:, 0, 8]
    # Haut => quelles sont les g inconnues en haut
    g[:, -1, 0] = gcoll[:, -1, 0]
    g[:, -1, 1:8] = gcoll[:, -1, 1:8]
    g[:, -1, 8] = gcoll[:, -1, 8]
    
def wall(g,mask):
    # Conditions de parois
    g[mask == 1, 1] = g[mask == 1, 3]
    g[mask == 1, 2] = g[mask == 1, 4]
    g[mask == 1, 3] = g[mask == 1, 1]
    g[mask == 1, 4] = g[mask == 1, 2]
    g[mask == 1, 5] = g[mask == 1, 7]
    g[mask == 1, 6] = g[mask == 1, 8]
    g[mask == 1, 7] = g[mask == 1, 5]
    g[mask == 1, 8] = g[mask == 1, 6]
    

#Calcul
geq,rho,ux,uy=init(M0=0.3)
g,gcoll=geq.copy(),geq.copy()
prof=np.zeros(nt) #profil de pression en fonction du temps

start=time.time()
for t in range(nt):
    collide(gcoll,g,geq,taug) # Collision
    propagate(g,gcoll) # Propagation
    boundary(g,gcoll) # Conditions aux limites domaine
    wall(g,mask)   # Conditions aux limites solides
    macro(g,rho,ux,uy) # Calcul des moments
    eq(geq,rho,ux,uy) # Calcul de l'equilibre
    prof[t]= rho[((cx1 + cx2) // 2) + 5*D, ((cy1 + cy2) // 2) + D] * c0**2 # Ecriture des résultats 
tcal=time.time()-start
print("Temps de calcul: "+str(tcal))
```

I tried to change the dimensions of rho, ux, and uy. But nothing really changed.

Edit: @Marcel suggested to call eq(geq, rho, ux, uy) in init function. But now I'm getting an error with the second line of the eq fuction, as shown above.

Comment: Your arguments to the `eq` function do not match the names you gave them! In the `init` function you should call `eq(geq, rho, ux, uy)`.

Comment: When you post about an error, you should copy and paste the entire error message here. It'll show the exact line that threw the error.

Comment: @Marcel: 
Thank you! Now I'm getting an error on the second line: 

  File c:\users\sayad\desktop\sanstitre0.py:72 in eq
    geq[:, :, 1:9] = w[1:] * rho * (1 + (c0**(-2)) * (ca[1:9, 0]*ux + ca[1:9, 1]*uy) + 0.5* (c0**-4) * (ca[1:9, 0]*ux + ca[1:9, 1]*uy)**2 - 0.5 * (c0**(-2)) * (ux**2 + uy**2))

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (8,) (80,40)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your math is right you have two errors:

First you're calling your function `eq` with the wrong arguments. Given my comment you already solved this.

Second, you need to expand the shapes of the incoming arrays to `eq` so that they can be broadcast together. Here's a fixed version:

```py
def eq(geq,rho,ux,uy):
    # Calcul de la fonction d'équilibre
    uxb = ux[:, :, None]
    uyb = uy[:, :, None]
    wb = w[None, None, :]
    cab = ca[None, None, 1:9, :]
    rhob = rho[:, :, None]
    geq[:, :, 0] = w[0] * rho * (1 - 0.5 * (c0**(-2)) * (ux**2 + uy**2))
    geq[:, :, 1:9] = wb[..., 1:] * (rhob * (1 + (c0**(-2)) * (cab[..., 0]*uxb + cab[..., 1]*uyb) + 0.5* (c0**-4) * (cab[..., 0]*uxb + cab[..., 1]*uyb)**2 - 0.5 * (c0**(-2)) * (uxb**2 + uyb**2)))
```

By the "b" suffix here, I mean something like "for broadcasting". Indexing with `None` will add a dimension to the array of size 1 in that position. For instance, if `arr` is of shape `(n, m)`, then `arr[:, :, None]` will be of shape `(n, m, 1)`.

Indexing with `arr[..., i]` means slicing the array at index `i` in the final dimension. For instance if `arr` is of shape `(n, m, l)`, then `arr[..., 0]` is the same as `arr[:, :, 0]`.

You can read about broadcasting in NumPy [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Note that `np.newaxis` has the same meaning as `None` when slicing an array.

Comment: Thank for your answer Marcel! Now I'm getting "nan" in g, gcoll, geq, rho, ux, and uy. resulting in problems in multiplication and division. I don't know if it's related to the math or the code.

Comment: @HighPressure, have you found the first place in your code where a NaN is produced?  As you debug, you can add `print(np.isnan(np.min(arr)))` for each array that you're checking.